# Rotation Lanscape collectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I used collection view to display 10 cells, with portraits:

[image]

and on rotation:

[image]

I just try code

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

  guard let followLayout = demoView.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
  return }

  followLayout.itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

  followLayout.invalidateLayout()

  view.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

but does not affect.

> I just try

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

guard let followLayout = detailView.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
  return
}

followLayout.invalidateLayout()

let offset = detailView.collectionView.contentOffset
let width = detailView.collectionView.bounds.size.width

let index = round(offset.x / width)
let newOffset = CGPoint(x: index * size.width, y: offset.y)

detailView.collectionView.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: false)

coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
  //      self.demoView.collectionView.reloadData()
  self.detailView.collectionView.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: false)
}, completion: nil)
```

}

and this work for me. Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to center align for every cell

### Swift 4

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

  let totalCellWidth = CellWidth * CellCount

  let totalSpacingWidth = CellSpacing * (CellCount - 1)

  let leftInset = (collectionViewWidth - CGFloat(totalCellWidth + totalSpacingWidth)) / 2

  let rightInset = leftInset

  return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftInset, 0, rightInset)

}
```

Comment: I just try this but does not effect. I Think use "viewWillTransition" but on rotation this reload another cell

Comment: @phúdươnghiển i think that should work , tell me if you had success